# Is there a closed form of the product $(1+a_1) (1+a_2)\cdots (1+a_N)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form, products

I have the following product
$$
P = \prod_{n=1}^N (1+a_n)
$$
where each $a_n$ is different. I know the expanded out form should be something like
$$
P = 1+\sum_n^N a_n + \sum_{n < m}^{N-1} a_n a_m + \sum_{n < m < q}^{N-2} a_n a_m a_q + \cdots  + a_1 a_2 \cdots a_N .
$$
How can I write that in a closed form, i.e. without the $+\cdots + $?

Comment: Notice that if you define $g(x)=\prod_{n=1}^N (x+a_n)$, then $P=g(1)$,I'm not sure what's the motivation for getting a closed form representation for the value of a polynomial at some point

Comment: You can write it is $ 1+\sum_{i=1}^N \sigma_i $, where the  $\sigma_i$s denote the elementary symmetric functions of $a_1,\dots, a_N$.

Comment: You've a representation of form $P=1+\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sigma_{j} (x)$ where $\sigma_j$ represent elementary symmetric polynomials in one variable, but I'm not sure, whether, this is of any help

Comment: How about $$\sum_{k=0}^N \sum_{1\le i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_k\le N} \prod_{j=1}^k a_{i_j}?$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not really a closed form, but if you're looking for a compact notation that lists all summands of the expanded product, it'd be this:

$$\sum_{S\subseteq \{1,...,N\}} \prod_{i\in S} a_i$$

(Be aware that the empty product is defined as: $\prod_{i\in \emptyset}a_n$=1)

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is an NxN matrix with eigenvalues $a_i$ and characteristic polynomial $p_A$ then
$$\det(I+A) = p_A(-1)=\prod_{n=1}^N (1+a_n)$$
Also, [$\det(I+A)$= sum of all principal minors of $A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1769864/detia-sum-of-all-principal-minors-of-a)